# Any advantage of sklearn wrappers for xgboost over python API?

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost, api

Are there any advantages of using the XGBoost sklearn wrappers `XGBRegressor` or `XGBClassifier` over using the Python API with the `train` method?
Is one faster than the other or does one use less memory than the other?
I am asking for a generic case where the data comes in some form which I convert to a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One advantage of using scikit-learn wrappers is that they are more likely to work within the scikit-learn ecosystem. For example, it might be easier to put the algorithm into pipelines.